# Pre-selecting values in a multi-select drop-down list in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm relatively new to Laravel (and using Laravel 4), but been around PHP and C# a long time.  Seems like this should be easy, but I can't find anywhere that tells me how to do this.

In my Controller I get the data from the database and send it to the view like this:

```
$sections = DB::table('paperSections')->lists('section','id');
return View::make('layouts.publisher.step2', array('sections' => $sections));
```

in my View, I have the following:

```
{{ Form::select('sections[]', $sections, '', array('multiple')) }}
```

which generates a select list like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="sections" name="sections">
<option value="1">News</option>
<option value="2">Sports</option>
<option value="3">Features</option>
<option value="4">Arts and Entertainment</option>
<option value="5">Technology and Science</option>
<option value="6">Op-Ed</option>
</select>
```

Lets assume I have a string (e.g. "1,3,5") which represents the multiple options selected previously.  How can I re-select those three options using that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass array of selected options as 3rd param:

```
$selected = explode(',', $idsAsString);

Form::select('sections[]', $sections, $selected, ['multiple'])
```